# Have a WPF Control Class being a template class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, templates, user-controls

is there a way to have a WPF UserControl Class to be a class with a Template type?
e.g.

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
```

should be:

```
public partial class MyControl<MyData> : UserControl
```

as I always get compile errors that `MyControl` than has no reference to `InitializeComponents` which is in the automatic generated part of the class.
The problem is, that I can't tell in the xaml part of the class that the usercontrol is of type `MyControl<MyData>`. I even tried `MyControl&lt;MyData&gt;` ...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Next time, please format code block by clicking the 101010 button, and format inline code using backticks (\`\`). This will make your angle brackets show up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I'll use the formating stuff next time!

Comment: Aha, I should have checked the source before posting my answer :-)  Nice work Thomas - I'll edit my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't declare a generic type in XAML.  From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/02ca0499-80af-4c56-bb80-f1185a619a9e:

> Hello, you can use generic as long as
>   you don’t use XAML. But unfortunately,
>   if you want to use XAML to define your
>   control, you can’t use generic…

You can create a control in XAML that inherits from a generic type by putting a [`x:TypeArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750476.aspx) attribute on the root tag, but the control itself must be concrete.

Comment: Thanks that link was very helpful.