# How to specify generic type argument in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a BaseView for my MVP - PRISM WPF application. Now for some reason we thought to make the _presenter as a Templated field in the BaseView.

earlier i had the view xaml representation as

```
<base:BaseView xamlns:base="clr address of the dll which had BaseView" >

</base:BaseView>
```

now since i have changed the  `BaseView` to `BaseView<TPresenter>,` So how shall i write the Xaml then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it since `.NET 4 Framework` and XAML 2009.
See [Generics in XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/generics-in-xaml) on MSDN

For instance:

```
<my:BusinessObject x:TypeArguments="x:String,x:Int32"/>
```

For .NET 3.5:

> For XAML 2006 usage when specifically targeting WPF, x:Class must also
>   be provided on the same element as x:TypeArguments, and that element
>   must be the root element in a XAML document. The root element must map
>   to a generic type with at least one type argument. An example is
>   PageFunction.
>
> Possible workarounds to support generic usages include defining a
>   custom markup extension that can return generic types, or providing a
>   wrapping class definition that derives from a generic type but
>   flattens the generic constraint in its own class definition.

Comment: can you tell me how it will look in my scenario where i wanna specifiy the TemplateArgument for a Root node of the view.

Comment: i jus came across this article, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/01/22/known-issue-controls-deriving-from-a-generic-base-class-must-be-in-separate-assembly.aspx which describes an existing issue. And i was able to mark the TypeArgument to get it working. Thanks Sll!

Comment: where can I get this "XAML 2009" thing? I have .Net 4.6.2 and still my wpf application is using XAML 2006?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary This is the standard and partially implemented in WPF, please read corresponding MSDN paper

Comment: @sll If it's possible, could you provide an example of how to actually use this? I put a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72047278/4601149) up before coming across this answer. I really appreciate any help

Comment: Working link for what @ioWint commented: https://web.archive.org/web/20140422181636/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/01/22/known-issue-controls-deriving-from-a-generic-base-class-must-be-in-separate-assembly.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In case this happens to someone.  I had a similar scenario where I converted my base class to a templated class (i.e. BaseView to BaseView). I kept receiving errors in the InitializeComponent() method.  I was receiving the null exception error in the x:Class base type's InitializeComponent() call.  I was able to resolve the errors by removing the form-level events from the XAML definition.  If I had to keep the form-level events I would need to move them to BaseView.