# Add Generics to XAML cs class

Tags: c#, xaml, generics

I am trying to add a generic Type to my XAML .cs file so it can be re-used with another classes/types. This is where I got so far:

```
public class PageElementRenderer<T> : PageFunction<T>
{
   public PageElementRenderer()
   {

   }
}
```

.cs behind XAML:

```
public partial class PageElementRenderer_Derived : PageElementRenderer<SomeClass>
{
   public PageElementRenderer_Derived() : base()
  {
  }
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:PageElementRenderer  
         x:Class="Application.PageElementRenderer_Derived"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Application">
```

I get an error:
***Using the generic type 'PageElementRenderer' requires 1 type arguments***
However, if I remove **T** *type parameter* from my pageElementRenderer class, everything works fine. Did I miss something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573712/how-to-specify-generic-type-argument-in-xaml

Comment: @RenéVogt But there are no types to specify for a derived type.

Comment: @DavidG my xaml know how is not the best, but the tag is `PageElementRenderer`, so even if the `Class` is `PageElementRenderer_Derived`, the parent type still would be a `PageElementRenderer<SomeClass>`, so the type arguments must be provided.

Comment: @RenéVogt Same here, been a while since I did XAML, but I was under the impression that the tag name was just the local name for the component and the `x:class` attribute was important. Easily testable by renaming it to `local:foo` I guess.

Comment: Thanks guys, adding `x:TypeArguments="local:SomeClass"` solved the problem!

Comment: In that case, shouldn't you have been using `<local:PageElementRenderer_Derived...`?

Comment: `SomeClass` is type parameter of `PageElementRenderer`, not `PageElementRenderer_Derived` so I presume `<local:PageElementRenderer...` is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, adding `x:TypeArguments="local:SomeClass"` solved the problem!